# Hilbert's finiteness theorem over arbitrary fields; reductive groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, invariant-theory

As a generalization of the finiteness result Hilbert proved in his 1890 paper, one usually formulates the following nowadays:

> Let $G\to\operatorname{GL}(V)$ be a rational representation of a linearly reductive group $G$ on a finite-dimensional $k$-vector space $V$. Then $k[V]^G$ is a finitely generated $k$-algebra.

The sources I looked at so far assume either $k=\mathbb{C}$, $k$ algebraically closed, or $k$ infinite. In what generality does this result hold, regarding $k$?

From the non-constructive proof of the result, I can't really see any reliance on $k$ being algebraically closed; just the existence of a Reynolds operator is needed. But $k$ algebraically closed or infinite is often assumed when reductive algebraic groups are defined. Any reference for this result with $k$ arbitrary or whatever the maximum generality is is greatly appreciated!

**Edit:** If I remember correctly, Emmy Noether proved the case $k$ arbitrary and $G$ a finite subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}_n(k)$ acting on the polynomial ring $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$. The only "problem" there could be is that in general $k[V]$ is not a polynomial ring if $k$ is a finite field.

Comment: So you're saying you only need to treat the finite field case?...

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva Basically, yes, but of course a reference to a book or paper that treats the theorem in full generality would be perfect.

Comment: About that proof from Noether, have you heard about Nagata's technique to prove the Noether normalization lemma? It works in the finite field case, I think this is related, although I'll admit I don't understand algebraic varieties very well, so that linearly reductive group thing you lost me. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms, by Cox, Little, and O'Shea, the theorem is shown for finite groups over any characteristic 0 field. The requirement that the field has characteristic 0 is clearly necessary if we want the Reynold's operator to be defined for arbitrary groups. The book doesn't really cover enough algebra to go into full generality for the linearly reductive case, so I'm not sure how this result carries over to that.

Comment: Hello Devlin, I'm definitely going to check out this book; didn't know they had a section with invariant theory. Thanks!

Comment: @Randal'Thor Also, today I came across a reference in Procesi and Schwarz, Inequalities Defining Orbit Spaces, that the result holds for real representations of compact Lie groups.